# Vim dot chained fucntions indent issue

Tags: vim, neovim

I have a problem with Vim in Insert Mode and JS dot chained functions indentations.

I will try to show a problem with a few code examples & screenshots:

In all modern editors:

```
document
  .querySelector('.btn-roll')
  .addEventListener('click', play)
  cursor position
```

in Vim:

```
document
  .querySelector('.btn-roll')
  .addEventListener('click', play)
cursor position
```

[image]

Does anyone know is there a way to fix it?

**UPDATE**

I think I found a solution with this plugin **pangloss/vim-javascript**

But is there any other solutions?

[image]